# Javascript reading old params from URL(GET method)

Tags: javascript, html

I am starting to learn JavaScript(coming from C++, Java, Python) and I am facing the following problem.
I want to make a simple login page, and pass the parameters like username and ppassword.
With the POST method, everything works.
Still, I wanted to try with the GET method where the parameters will be put in the URL, just to see the difference.
The problem is that JS function always reads old values, so at the beginning after I click submit, it reads null for both username and password(because the starting link doesnt have any params) and later it always reads the old ones.
It seems like URL doesnt update before JS script runs.

Any idea on how to solve this?

```js
function validate() {
  var queryString = window.location.href;
  var url = new URL(queryString);
  var username = url.searchParams.get('username')
  var password = url.searchParams.get('password')
  console.log(username);
  console.log(password);
  if (username == "admin" && password == "admin") {
    alert("login successfully");
  } else {
    alert("login failed");
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="box" action="login.html" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" id="username">
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" id="password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

Comment: Here you're submitting the form on login.html and calling the validate on click so its contradictory actions happening. This will not resolve your problem.

Comment: _"It seems like URL doesnt update before JS script runs."_ - no, it does not. Your event handler executes first, before the browser actually submits the form. (If that wasn't the case, then it would be impossible to use such event handlers to _intercept_ a form submission.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the code into two files, one for `home.html` that contains the UI elements and form submit will pass the data to another file `login.html`. Also, removing the click event as it is already on submit type form will automatically submit the data to `login.html` given in submitting action.

**Login.html**

```
<script>
  var queryString = window.location.href;

  var url = new URL(queryString);

  var username = url.searchParams.get("username");
  var password = url.searchParams.get("password");

  console.log(username);
  console.log(password);

  if (username == "admin" && password == "admin") {
    alert("login successfully");
  } else {
    alert("login failed");
  }
</script>
```

**home.html**

```
<form class="box" action="login.html" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" id="username">
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" id="password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
</form>
```

[image]

[image]